# Two horizontal div with right div scrolls when resizing

Tags: html, css

I want to have two horizontal divs.
The width of the left div is 200px and is fixed. 
The width of the right div is 600px by default and should be responsive. If user resizes the browser, the width of right div may decrease and scroll bar appears on right div.

I am trying to use float and overflow to do it. But I can't think of the right solution.
What should I do?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Show some of your code blocks using fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for getting better result.

```
 <div class="main">
   <div class="left">sdfsf</div>
   <div class="right">sfsdfdsfsfdsfds</div>
 </div>

 .main{display:table; width:100%;}
 .left
 {
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:200px;
    width:200px;    
    border:1px solid red;
 }
.right
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/39x176wg/)

Comment: Not what the user wants, they don't want the body to overflow, they want the right div to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I don't like `display:table`:

it is possible to achieve what you're looking for using `flexbox`.

The idea is to set the `right` element's width using `width:100%` and the `left` using `width: 200px; min-width:200px`.

I'm not sure what you mean regarding the overflow, but my solution has the `right` element's `overflow` set to `scroll`, and the contentn is put within another `div` whose `width` is `600px`

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxbpcn9c/4/).

Comment: Billy wants a *horizontal* scrollbar.

Comment: Update the right `div`'s `overflow` to `overflow-x` and that would work too though you've pumped CSS up to CSS level 3 so it is technically less compatible though the OP hasn't mentioned any browser requirements.

Comment: Actually, `flexbox` is quite well supported if you get the prefixes right. The amazing [flexbox.less](https://github.com/ProLoser/Flexbox.less) is pretty handy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a bit odd and *can* be done though not using purely CSS level 1 unfortunately. In order to have the elements "`float`" *and* have the second `div` overflow instead of the `body` element you'll have to use a combination of `position` and `overflow`.

Copy this to an (x)html file and resize the browser...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden">

<div style="overflow: auto; max-width: 800px;">
<div style="background-color: #ff0; height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">left</div>

<div style="background-color: #0ff; height: 200px; overflow-x: auto; position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 0px; max-width: 600px;">
<div style="min-width: 800px;">right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, right child, </div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I highly recommend **not** using this even if your browser support requirement is extremely relaxed simply because using static layouts alone is really IE6 era sort of in-the-box-of-a-box type thinking. If it's for a client you really need to force-override them.

Comment: Your answer has the right div overflow out of the screen on mobile device.